# Joda time saves invalid date through hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jodatime

I am having issue storing a date while converting it from String to Date Time.

Below is the code,

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

String date1 = "2017-11-02";

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");

someHibernateMethod.setTransactionDate1(formatter.parseDateTime(date1));
someHibernateMethod.setTransactionDate2(DateTime.now());
```

date1 saved as - "2017-11-01 19:00:00.000", but when I save date with DateTime.Now() it saves correctly.

I am expecting **"2017-11-02 00:00:00.000"** for date1

Comment: I smell a timezone problem... are you in gmt+5 maybe?

Comment: yes...in US Central zone. When I debug this issue in my local, I get this value - "2017-11-02T00:00:00.000-05:00"

Comment: I would suggest you do a printout of `formatter.parseDateTime(date1)` first before persisting it. So you determine the actual output from the formatter.

Comment: sure, let me try doing that and see if it works.

Comment: Tried it, but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution as below,

```
String date1 = "2017-11-02";

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
LocalDate localDate = formatter.parseLocalDate(date1);
DateTime newDate= localDate.toDateTime(new LocalTime());
someHibernateMethod.setTransactionDate1(newDate)
```